# Asp net boilerplate authorization. Implementation IPermissionChecker

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, aspnetboilerplate

I have several web services. 
`Auth`- authentification with users, roles, clients. Other services - some buisness logic. In authentification server user or client get token and then use it in buisness logic services.
To implement authorization i should implement IPermissionChecker interface. It have method:

```
Task<bool> IsGrantedAsync(UserIdentifier user, string permissionName);
Task<bool> IsGrantedAsync(string permissionName);
```

UserIdentifier have only UserId and TenantId.  My buisness servises have no users, roles, it is store only permissions for users, clients, roles and get user id, roles id, client id in token.

I can implement permission cheking only for current user by getting information from current context claims. Is there is any way to check permissions through claims. Should i implement it for not currrent user if i not plannig to run anything behalf not current user?

I user asp net boilerplate core + module zero + identity server 4 for Auth server.
Buisness servers use asp net boilerplate .net full.

Comment: Question is not clear. Don't store the permissions in the claim. Claims are just for generic bits of user data like Locale or ID. Always check the current permissions server side (what if a permission changes server side? Of course you don't want to use the old permission on the claim right?)

Comment: I dont want to store in services database information about users and roles. I want store information only about granted permisions for userid and roleid, and get `userid` and `roleid` in claims. i implemented it for current session user, but there is some method in `IPermissionChecker` with `UserIdentifier` that difficult to implement because this class have no role link. I there is any way to extend `Useridentifier` with role? Can i not implement this method?

Comment: Roles are just a group of permissions. You are supposed to check permissions individually depending on what you are trying to do.